# slideToggle() cant use if else for multiple choices

Tags: javascript, html, css, slidetoggle

I want to use `slidetoggle()` function to do multiple thing i used if else but it wont work can you help me
the javaScript code explains whats i was about to do i was going to create three panels and three  clicks to activate these panels but it didnt work

```css
[enter image description here`<script> 
$(document).ready(
function(){

$("#flip").click(function(){$("#panel").slideToggle("slow");});
}
function(){

$("#flip").click(function(){$("#panell").slideToggle("slow");});
}
function(){

$("#flip").click(function(){$("#panelll").slideToggle("slow");});
}
);
</script>`]
[1]

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/** { 
  outline: 1px solid black;
}*/

#header_buttons {
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
 height:150px;
}
#header_buttons a:hover{text-decoration: underline;}
#header_buttons li, a {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 4px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
}


#sign_in {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #29A0F0;
    padding-top: 0px;
 margin-right:15px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

li#sign_in {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#sign_in:hover{box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #e6e6e6;}
#sign_in a {
    margin: 0 auto;
/*        border:1px solid black;
*/
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#sign-in-text {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
/*DAMN -- This was/is CONFUSING but it sets the sign-in button properties*/
div#header_buttons ul li#sign_in {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
/*    border: 1px solid black;
*/    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
#sign_in a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
}

#google_logo {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#google_logo > img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#query {
    width: 572px;
    margin: auto;
}
#query > input {
    width:572px;
    height:30px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url("images/microphone.png");
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#query input[type="text"] {
font-size: 17px;
}

.buttons {
    width: 572px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

button#search {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font: bold 11px Arial, sans-serif !important;
    width: 150px;
    height: 33px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
}
button#lucky {
    font: bold 11px Arial, sans-serif !important;
    width: 150px;
    height: 33px;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    min-height: 15px;
    width: 100%;
 height:33px;
/*    border: 1px solid black;
*/    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}




#footer-left ul li{
    float: left;
/*    border:1px solid black;
*/    display: inline;
    padding: 5px 3px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}


#footer-left ul li a{
/*        border:1px solid black;
*/
    padding: 30px 8px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer-right ul li
{
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    padding: 30px 8px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}


#footer-right ul li a{
    padding: 30px 8px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
#flip {
    text-align: center;
    background-image:url("9blocks.png");
 width:16px;
 height:16px;
    border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
    display: none;
}


#panell {
    display: none;
}


#panelll {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(
function(){

    $("#flip").click(function(){$("#panel").slideToggle("slow");});
}
function(){

    $("#flip").click(function(){$("#panell").slideToggle("slow");});
}
function(){

    $("#flip").click(function(){$("#panelll").slideToggle("slow");});
}
);
</script>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Google</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="head.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header_buttons">
         <ul>

<!-- <li id="gmail"><a style="margin-right:5px;margin-top:50px" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm">Gmail</a></li>
<li id="you"><a style="margin-right:35px;margin-top:50px" href="https://plus.google.com/?gpsrc=ogpy0&amp;tab=wX">Images</a></li> -->

 <li id="sign_in"><a id="sign-in-text" href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&amp;continue=https://www.google.com/">Sign In</a></li>
<div id="flip" style="margin-left: 735px;margin-top: -47px;" ></div>
<div id="panel">
<img src="untitled.png" style="margin-left:635px;margin-top:0px;" width="179" height="200" alt="Planets" usemap"#planetmap">
<map name="planetmap">
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="4,1,49,54" href="1" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="65,2,109,54" href="2" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="124,1,174,59" href="3" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="6,69,50,125" href="4" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="63,66,110,126" href="5" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="121,68,172,129" href="6" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="6,140,47,192" href="7" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="67,139,113,194" href="8" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="128,142,172,194" href="9" target="_self" />
</map>
</div> 
<div id="flip" style="margin-left: 635px;margin-top: -17px;" ></div>
<div id="panell">
<img src="untitled1.png" style="margin-right:210px;margin-top:0px;" width="61" height="200" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
<map name="planetmap">
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="4,1,49,54" href="1" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="6,69,50,125" href="4" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="6,140,47,192" href="7" target="_self" />
</map>
</div>
<div id="flip" style="margin-left: 535px;margin-top: -17px;" ></div>
<div id="panelll">
<img src="untitled2.png" style="margin-right:320px;margin-top:0px;" width="179" height="60" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
<map name="planetmap">
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="4,1,49,54" href="1" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="65,2,109,54" href="2" target="_self" />
<area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="124,1,174,59" href="3" target="_self" />
</map>
</div>
   
   


    <div class="button"> <i class="fa fa-th fa-2x"></i> </div>

         </ul>
    </div>

      <div id="google_logo">
         <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
      </div>
      <div id=query>
         <input type="text"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
         <button  type="submit" value="Submit" id="search">Google Search</button>
         <button id="lucky">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
         <div id="footer-left">
            <ul>
               <li><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/ads/?fg=1">Advertising</a></li>
               <li><a>Business</a></li>
               <li><a>About</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div id="footer-right">
            <ul>
                               <li><a>Privacy & Terms</a></li>
                  <li><a>Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>   
</html>
```

Comment: no actually it didnt work you see i have three click buttons and three panels i want each panel to operate independently on its (button like img) click

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass multiple callbacks like this, Try the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
       $("#panel, #panell, #panelll").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

`"#panel, #panell, #panelll"` will select all these three elements in single selector.

Comment: no actually it didnt work you see i have three click buttons and three panels i want each panel to operate independently on its (button like img) click

Comment: @divy3993 could you post another question?

Comment: @user2970163 if they are three buttons then how can they have same id?